# Cannot debug with Visual Studio Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-lightswitch

Please help with Visual Studio Lightswitch/Visual Studio Express.

I have a solution with a nunit tests project. To run unit tests I am using the below line, which attaches the debugger to the nunit runner.

```
NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

Under Visual Studio Express it works fine but when this solution is opened with Lightswitch I am getting an error saying "The debugger is not properly installed".

I tried to debug from ReSharper's runner, which gives an error saying "Cannot launch debugger. Error code: -1989083114". Simply running tests with ReSharper works fine.

Any help appreciated!

**[NOTE]**

Just to make sure I'm clear: No, this is not a Lightwitch application but I want to use VS Lightswitch to have ReSharper, which is not available for Express. Also Lightswitch does have some more features than Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible with Lightswitch, at least according to the guys [at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/3a8a27b2-26b8-4dea-86e1-80e7f512cac5/)